# QGIS failing to download WMTS capabilities

Tags: qgis, wmts

Is anyone aware of an issue with WMTS layers in QGIS 3.1.8?

When I create the connection I get the "failed to download capabilities" error. I can add this WMTS into another GIS software just fine and also browsers return the capabilities as expected when requesting 
...?request=getcapabilities&service=wmts
I can add WMS from the same server to QGIS with no issues. 
It's a local WMS/WMTS so can't share the publicly accessible URL.

[image]

Comment: Is the ?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS& response valid XML?

Comment: Yes, it is. And holds all the information about my data as expected. Is there any trick when adding the connection to QGIS? I tried many variations of the URL but nothing works. Looking at QGIS docs looks like it should work as WMS (which does work).

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to see what actual request is sent by QGIS, what the actual response is from the server, and any errors reported, as it's not always available in the console

Comment: OK, so it looks like the request is being created incorrectly as the the service is WMS instead of WMTS. Is this an issue on QGIS side or my OGC service configuration? How are those parameters added to the URL? I don't seem to be able to attach a screenshot here but the failing request is: GET /###/wmts.exe?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities HTTP/1.1

Of course when I test in the browser I add the service parameter manually so then it works correctly. Still confused why another GIS software doesn't have issues getting the capabilities.

Comment: In my WMTS configuration I definitely have the service configured as WMTS: OGC_SERVICE=WMTS

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is caused by QGIS proxy settings.
You can check the Settings/Options/Network Proxy type list.
[image]
If you have any proxy settings, select "HttpProxy" and enter your "Host", "Port", and "User" information.
In my case, DefaultProxy settings solved my problem.